# Проблемы с PyDev и Eclipse

Tags: python, pydev, eclipse

Скачал Eclipse Standard с оф. сайта. Через маркет установил плагин PyDev. При установке не возникло никаких ошибок, но в "создать проект" нету создать Python проекта. Python нету и в нстройках(Window->Preferences).
Чтобы было понятнее, вот пару скринов:
[image]

Во, собственно и окно настроек:
[image]

Смотрел, в папке plugins есть много папок, имена которых содержат PyDev. 
Он как бы установлен, но эклипс его не видит.

P.S: С эклипс раньше никогда не работал, собираюсь питон осваивать

P.P.S: Debian wheezy 7.3, Eclipse Standard 4.3

Answer (score 1):

Сам и нашел ответ:). Оказывается все просто, нашел решение на [оф. сайте](http://pydev.org/download.html#pydev-does-not-appear-after-install) PyDev, вот ссылка. Извините за беспокойство.